# Using git submodule update fails but git clone directly works well

Tags: git

There are submodules in the project and I use following command to clone submodules recursively.

```
$ Git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@gitlab.devtools.intel.com:29418/ipg-sh/mcf/mcf_fw.git
Cloning into 'C:/Users/peterwei/mcf_fw/modules/bsp/hal/intel'...
Welcome to Intel Hardened OS
remote: Enumerating objects: 81, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done. 
remote: Total 859 (delta 28), reused 34 (delta 6), pack-reused 778
Receiving objects: 100% (859/859), 231.22 KiB | 432.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (267/267), done.
```

The result is that the folder only contains .git file, as below.

[image]

However, if I cd into the folder 'C:/Users/peterwei/mcf_fw/modules/bsp/hal/intel' and do clone with following command

```
$ git clone ssh://git@gitlab.devtools.intel.com:29418/ipg-sh/modules/bsp/hal_intel.git
Cloning into 'hal_intel'...
Welcome to Intel Hardened OS
remote: Enumerating objects: 81, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
remote: Total 859 (delta 28), reused 34 (delta 6), pack-reused 778
Receiving objects: 100% (859/859), 231.22 KiB | 457.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (267/267), done.
```

I can download all files successfully.

[image]

What's the difference and why the git submodule method doesn't work well?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is: you have created a nested Git repository inside a subfolder you your main repository. That nested repo content will be ignored by the parent repository.

Try a `git submodule update --init` inside your main repository (after having removed any nested repo manually cloned)

Check what URL is registered in your main repo `.gitmodules` file.